# ProductListingDetails null on eBay API GetItem Call

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I've recently been working with the eBay API trying to get orders and their item details. In the API documentation it tells you you need to specify the `DetailCodeType` to get the `ProductListingDetails`.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html

The `ProductListingDetails` object contains `Brand`, `Model`, `MPN`, among other things I need, but it always returns as null. Even though I have that data set in the item listing. This is an issue on both the live site and their sandbox environment.

Has anyone else ran into this issue and know of a solution where I can get these details using the eBay API? My code is below:

```
public static ItemType GetItem(string itemId)
{
    GetItemCall itemCall = new GetItemCall(apiContext);
    itemCall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);

    return itemCall.GetItem(itemId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a workaround for this. When logged into your selling account you can go to Subscriptions and subscribe to the Selling Manager for free. Then going into the selling manager and selecting Active on the left sidebar will take you to a new screen. A Customize link will show up on the top. Select the Custom Label checkbox and you can add custom data to a listing item.

That is returned in the item data as the `SKU` field. I just needed a way to input custom data that was returned from eBay API and this worked great. Below is an article that explains it as well.

http://support.atandra.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/124/0/how-to-enable-sku-custom-label-field-on-ebay

Answer (score 0):

Note: For `GetSellerList` (returning multiple items at once) they have removed `Item.ProductListingDetails`. I think this happened a while ago but I haven't updated my API version in YEARS. So just finding this out now.

> Item.ProductListingDetails (modified): In a multiple-variation
>   listing, the product identifier (EAN, ISBN or UPC) for a product
>   variation should be returned in the
>   Variation.VariationProductListingDetails container instead.

It doesn't *actually* say that `Item.ProductListingDetails` is always null, but my code that used to work no longer works so I think it's deprecated for `GetSellerList`.

It is still present in `GetItem`.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getsellerlist.html

Comment: Oh and DetailLevel, Granularity or which seller plan you're on don't make any difference.